# oracle sleep function on select statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have one complex ETL jobs which hung  most of the time when it runs(generally during peak time, non peak time it runs in 10Min).

It has around 15 complex SQLs, all triggers in parallel. functionally i can run few queries in sequential instead of all at once(helps reduce resource consumption).

since ETL jobs is complex, redesign will take time. is there any way i can set timing on some queries to start late( like SLEEP). ETL will trigger all at once but when  it reaches DB query should wait instead of executing.

ex. Query 1:

```
select col1, col2 from table1 -- start after 2min
```

Query 2:

```
select col1, col2 from table2 -- start after 5min
```

i know it is very odd question. apologies for that.

Comment: What mechanism do you use to run these ETL queries?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `DBMS_LOCK.SLEEP` procedure to suspend the session for specified number of seconds.

For example, I will add `10 seconds` of sleep between two queries:

```
SQL> set time on timing on
01:12:45 SQL> SELECT * FROM DUAL;

D
-
X

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
01:12:45 SQL> EXEC DBMS_LOCK.sleep(10); --> sleep for 10 seconds

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Elapsed: 00:00:10.00 --> You could see it paused for 10 seconds
01:12:55 SQL> SELECT * FROM DUAL;

D
-
X

Elapsed: 00:00:00.00
```

From **18c** onward, the `SLEEP` procedure is added to the `DBMS_SESSION` package and **deprecated** from the `DBMS_LOCK` package. This is really very useful as `DBMS_SESSION` is **available to all sessions with no additional grants needed** unlike the `DBMS_LOCK` package which doesn't have execute privilege by default.

Comment: The Seeker has tagged their question `[oracle11g]` which means they must use `dbms_lock.sleep()`. It's worth mentioning that execute on DBMS_LOCK is not granted by default and they will need to ask their DBA for the privilege. This is the main reason why `dbms_session.sleep()` is such a boon.

Comment: @APC Thanks for the edit, that was a typo. The demo I gave uses `DBMS_LOCK`. Good point about the privilege, worth mentioning in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, this  ETL specific type/job takes only SELECT statement.  don't have option for Sleep command.  i was looking something like HINT. ETL will submit the SELECT to oracle but oracle delays actual execution of SQL.   looks like mine is strange requirement. i might need to re-deign that complex ETL.